# S-curve in residuals plot: a problem?

Tags: regression, residuals

I am doing some linear regression and am predicting a absolutely non-normal dependent variable (for context: we are forecasting the amount of units sold for a shop). Therefore, we have transformed the variable to its natural log. The residuals do now have an s-curve.[image: Here is a picture of the residuals plot]

I reckon that it means that the distribution is short-tailed.Should I do anything about this or what effects does it have on the validity of my forecast?

Edit:
I have two more pictures for you, I hope this will help in getting an answer.

[image: QQ plot natural log transform]

[image: QQ plot untransformed]

Comment: "Number of units" would be discrete and non-negative (in fact, a count). You'd expect the response to be both right skew and heteroskedastic; in some situations the log you tried might work okay, but in many cases it won't. You might be better off investigating GLMs, perhaps a negative binomial model (possibly with log-link). [The appearance of this plot may be due to other aspects of model inadequacy. What were other displays like, such as residuals vs fitted? Do you have a Q-Q plot, preferably with the known values (the expected quantiles) on the x-axis?]

Comment: Martin, please merge your accounts. Then you will be able to edit your own question. You can find out how in our [help].

Comment: How about a Q-Q plot _of the residuals_? The plot of the marginal response isn't worth much in regression modeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An S-shape P-P plot indicates that the distribution has the correct median. The "flattening" of the S means that the distribution has tails that are about as long as those of the normal distribution. So your tails aren't "short". Rather, the density decays faster to meet a tail of the same length as the Gaussian distribution.

This *alone* does not pose a problem for generating forecasts, because the symmetry in the plot (the S isn't badly lopsided) suggests that the residuals are distributed more or less symmetrically. That means that your forecasts, on the log scale, are overestimates about as often as they are underestimates. Depending on the kinds of forecasting you care about, this is as good as you'd hope for.

Making inferences about those forecasts is probably also safe, because of the large sample size and because the tails "match" those of the theoretical distribution.

The rapid decay implies that the bulk of your estimates are accurate (good!), but there is a relatively wide spread of inaccurate estimates. That could indicate nothing, or it could indicate there's some kind of problem with your model. This is why it would be good to see a Q-Q plot of the residuals, a plot of residuals vs fitted, and a plot of fitted vs actual on the *original* scale.